# Run JavaScript function for every two times a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

For my web app, I need some javascript code which will run every two times a button is clicked. I've tried so many different things but I can't quite get it right. Because I'm a rookie coder I can't get any code demos on what I've done but I would really appreciate your help anyways.

Comment: *"every 2 times a button is clicked"* You mean double-clicked?

Comment: You must show us what have you done

Comment: No, double clicking is doing it really fast, its just every 2 times a button is clicked, so, on the first click nothing happens, on the second click, javascript function runs, and the third click, nothing happens, fourth click javascript runs and so on

Comment: I tried everything, I really cant, there is no good code and I lost the best code I did!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dblclick there is an event called dblclick. you should be able to use it. so elem.addEventListener('dblclick', yourFunc);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple approach using an index to keep track of even/oddness:

```js
const fn = e => outElem.innerHTML += "clicked!<br>";
const outElem = document.getElementById("output");
let i = 0;

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", e => i++ & 1 ? fn(e) : false);
```

```html
<button id="btn">click</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Help appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do that:

```js
var clicked = 0;

function myFunction() {

  clicked++;

  console.log(clicked)
  
  if (clicked === 2) {
    alert('i like cats');
    clicked = 0;
  };

};
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">click me twice!</button>
```

Comment: It keeps showing the alert after clicking the 2nd click.

Comment: just remove the clicked = 1 in the if statement, I  already updated it.

Comment: Don't worry: Managed to change the code myself, where it says if (clicked === 2) { changed it to if (clicked == 2) {

Comment: hope you can solve your question, that's very basic, but you will get this kind of logic with time, dont be afraid of asking :)

Comment: I fixed it in the answer - you had to reset the counter after the when is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. Replace the action method with your custom method

```
<button onclick="clicked()">Click Me</button>
```

```js
function action() {
  console.log('Do something here')
}
var counter = 0;
function clicked() {
  if (counter === 2) {
    action();
    counter = 0;
  }
  counter++;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clicked()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<button onclick="clickFunction()">click me twice!</button>

<script>
var eventClick = 0;

function clickFunction() {
  eventClick++;  
  if (eventClick === 2) {
    alert('Clicked');
    eventClick = 0;
  };

};
</script>
```